# XGBoost feature importance - only shows two features

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost

I would like to see all of the features in the set I am sending to the XGBoost model in-terms of importance. I seem to only ever see two. The good news is it does look like 2 of the set that should be identified as important. However, I would really like to see all of the features. There are a total of 20 features in the training set. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The default for plot_importance is to show all of the features (I looked at the code to confirm).

https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html

**max_num_features** *(int, default None) – Maximum number of top features displayed on plot. If None, all features will be displayed.*

Code to show the plot:

```
import shap
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as pl

xgb.plot_importance(model,max_num_features=None)
pl.title("xgboost.plot_importance(model)")
pl.show()
```

When I look at the tuples or booster.get_scores from the model I see the same two:

```
{'locations': 80, 'avg_loc_dist': 20}
```

Graph:
[image]

Added plot_tree image:
[image]

Comment: It seems like your xgboost model uses only these two features to predict the outcome. It probably means that using these two features are just enough to predict the outcome. Or, it may be something related to your choice of model parameters, for example max_depth of the model.

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't thought of depth. I will look at that. I was wondering the same thing, that it might be just related to that it really uses just those two.

Comment: Played with the max depth and didn't see a change. Just really wanted to most/all even if the contribution is small.

Comment: You may want to try to plot the xgboost tree to see if it is using just those two features. The tree can be plotted using xgb.plot_tree()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the answer/help from folks on the XGBoost forum. I am posting the response (and link) here for others that might encounter the same issue.

The reason those are the only two features showing up is that those are the only two in the splits. They suggested use xgb.dump_model() to view that in the dump, which I was able to see. Just ignorance, lack of understanding on my part.

Repsonse:

```
Most likely only these two features are being used in the splits. You can verify this by running xgb.dump_model() to get the text representation of the model.
```

https://discuss.xgboost.ai/t/xgboost-feature-importance-only-shows-two-features/1541/2

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to use [`permutation_importance`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.inspection.permutation_importance.html#sklearn.inspection.permutation_importance) from `scikit-learn`.

I see that you imported `shap` package, the `shap` package has the importance plot available:

```py
shap.summary_plot(shap_values, X_test, plot_type="bar")
```

Both methods should help to debug the model. You can read more details about different ways to compute feature importance in Xgboost in this [blog post](https://mljar.com/blog/feature-importance-xgboost/) of mine.